# Fastest method to find all item types with python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I have 5 item types that I have to parse thousands of files (approximately 20kb - 75kb) for:

```
Item Types
SHA1 hashes 
ip addresses
domain names
urls (full thing if possible)
email addresses
```

I currently use regex to find any items of these nature in thousands of files. 
python regex is taking a really long time and I was wondering if there is a better method to identify these item types anywhere in any of my text based flat files?

```
reSHA1 = r"([A-F]|[0-9]|[a-f]){40}"
reIPv4 = r"\b(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)(\.|\[\.\])){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)"
reURL = r"[A-Z0-9\-\.\[\]]+(\.|\[\.\])(XN--CLCHC0EA0B2G2A9GCD|XN--HGBK6AJ7F53BBA|" \
        r"XN--HLCJ6AYA9ESC7A|XN--11B5BS3A9AJ6G|XN--MGBERP4A5D4AR|XN--XKC2DL3A5EE0H|XN--80AKHBYKNJ4F|" \
        r"XN--XKC2AL3HYE2A|XN--LGBBAT1AD8J|XN--MGBC0A9AZCG|XN--9T4B11YI5A|XN--MGBAAM7A8H|XN--MGBAYH7GPA|" \
        r"XN--MGBBH1A71E|XN--FPCRJ9C3D|XN--FZC2C9E2C|XN--YFRO4I67O|XN--YGBI2AMMX|XN--3E0B707E|XN--JXALPDLP|" \
        r"XN--KGBECHTV|XN--OGBPF8FL|XN--0ZWM56D|XN--45BRJ9C|XN--80AO21A|XN--DEBA0AD|XN--G6W251D|XN--GECRJ9C|" \
        r"XN--H2BRJ9C|XN--J6W193G|XN--KPRW13D|XN--KPRY57D|XN--PGBS0DH|XN--S9BRJ9C|XN--90A3AC|XN--FIQS8S|" \
        r"XN--FIQZ9S|XN--O3CW4H|XN--WGBH1C|XN--WGBL6A|XN--ZCKZAH|XN--P1AI|MUSEUM|TRAVEL|AERO|ARPA|ASIA|COOP|" \
        r"INFO|JOBS|MOBI|NAME|BIZ|CAT|COM|EDU|GOV|INT|MIL|NET|ORG|PRO|TEL|XXX|AC|AD|AE|AF|AG|AI|AL|AM|AN|AO|AQ|" \
        r"AR|AS|AT|AU|AW|AX|AZ|BA|BB|BD|BE|BF|BG|BH|BI|BJ|BM|BN|BO|BR|BS|BT|BV|BW|BY|BZ|CA|CC|CD|CF|CG|CH|CI|CK|" \
        r"CL|CM|CN|CO|CR|CU|CV|CW|CX|CY|CZ|DE|DJ|DK|DM|DO|DZ|EC|EE|EG|ER|ES|ET|EU|FI|FJ|FK|FM|FO|FR|GA|GB|GD|GE|" \
        r"GF|GG|GH|GI|GL|GM|GN|GP|GQ|GR|GS|GT|GU|GW|GY|HK|HM|HN|HR|HT|HU|ID|IE|IL|IM|IN|IO|IQ|IR|IS|IT|JE|JM|JO|" \
        r"JP|KE|KG|KH|KI|KM|KN|KP|KR|KW|KY|KZ|LA|LB|LC|LI|LK|LR|LS|LT|LU|LV|LY|MA|MC|MD|ME|MG|MH|MK|ML|MM|MN|MO|" \
        r"MP|MQ|MR|MS|MT|MU|MV|MW|MX|MY|MZ|NA|NC|NE|NF|NG|NI|NL|NO|NP|NR|NU|NZ|OM|PA|PE|PF|PG|PH|PK|PL|PM|PN|PR|" \
        r"PS|PT|PW|PY|QA|RE|RO|RS|RU|RW|SA|SB|SC|SD|SE|SG|SH|SI|SJ|SK|SL|SM|SN|SO|SR|ST|SU|SV|SX|SY|SZ|TC|TD|TF|" \
        r"TG|TH|TJ|TK|TL|TM|TN|TO|TP|TR|TT|TV|TW|TZ|UA|UG|UK|US|UY|UZ|VA|VC|VE|VG|VI|VN|VU|WF|WS|YE|YT|ZA|ZM|ZW)" \
        r"(/\S+)"
reDomain = r"[A-Z0-9\-\.\[\]]+(\.|\[\.\])(XN--CLCHC0EA0B2G2A9GCD|XN--HGBK6AJ7F53BBA|XN--HLCJ6AYA9ESC7A|" \
           r"XN--11B5BS3A9AJ6G|XN--MGBERP4A5D4AR|XN--XKC2DL3A5EE0H|XN--80AKHBYKNJ4F|XN--XKC2AL3HYE2A|" \
           r"XN--LGBBAT1AD8J|XN--MGBC0A9AZCG|XN--9T4B11YI5A|XN--MGBAAM7A8H|XN--MGBAYH7GPA|XN--MGBBH1A71E|" \
           r"XN--FPCRJ9C3D|XN--FZC2C9E2C|XN--YFRO4I67O|XN--YGBI2AMMX|XN--3E0B707E|XN--JXALPDLP|XN--KGBECHTV|" \
           r"XN--OGBPF8FL|XN--0ZWM56D|XN--45BRJ9C|XN--80AO21A|XN--DEBA0AD|XN--G6W251D|XN--GECRJ9C|XN--H2BRJ9C|" \
           r"XN--J6W193G|XN--KPRW13D|XN--KPRY57D|XN--PGBS0DH|XN--S9BRJ9C|XN--90A3AC|XN--FIQS8S|XN--FIQZ9S|" \
           r"XN--O3CW4H|XN--WGBH1C|XN--WGBL6A|XN--ZCKZAH|XN--P1AI|MUSEUM|TRAVEL|AERO|ARPA|ASIA|COOP|INFO|JOBS|" \
           r"MOBI|NAME|BIZ|CAT|COM|EDU|GOV|INT|MIL|NET|ORG|PRO|TEL|XXX|AC|AD|AE|AF|AG|AI|AL|AM|AN|AO|AQ|AR|AS|AT" \
           r"|AU|AW|AX|AZ|BA|BB|BD|BE|BF|BG|BH|BI|BJ|BM|BN|BO|BR|BS|BT|BV|BW|BY|BZ|CA|CC|CD|CF|CG|CH|CI|CK|CL|CM|" \
           r"CN|CO|CR|CU|CV|CW|CX|CY|CZ|DE|DJ|DK|DM|DO|DZ|EC|EE|EG|ER|ES|ET|EU|FI|FJ|FK|FM|FO|FR|GA|GB|GD|GE|GF|GG|" \
           r"GH|GI|GL|GM|GN|GP|GQ|GR|GS|GT|GU|GW|GY|HK|HM|HN|HR|HT|HU|ID|IE|IL|IM|IN|IO|IQ|IR|IS|IT|JE|JM|JO|JP|" \
           r"KE|KG|KH|KI|KM|KN|KP|KR|KW|KY|KZ|LA|LB|LC|LI|LK|LR|LS|LT|LU|LV|LY|MA|MC|MD|ME|MG|MH|MK|ML|MM|MN|MO|MP" \
           r"|MQ|MR|MS|MT|MU|MV|MW|MX|MY|MZ|NA|NC|NE|NF|NG|NI|NL|NO|NP|NR|NU|NZ|OM|PA|PE|PF|PG|PH|PK|PL|PM|PN|PR|" \
           r"PS|PT|PW|PY|QA|RE|RO|RS|RU|RW|SA|SB|SC|SD|SE|SG|SH|SI|SJ|SK|SL|SM|SN|SO|SR|ST|SU|SV|SX|SY|SZ|TC|TD|TF" \
           r"|TG|TH|TJ|TK|TL|TM|TN|TO|TP|TR|TT|TV|TW|TZ|UA|UG|UK|US|UY|UZ|VA|VC|VE|VG|VI|VN|VU|WF|WS|YE|YT|ZA|" \
           r"ZM|ZW)\b"
reEmail = r"\b[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+(@|\[@\])[A-Za-z0-9.-]+(\.|\[\.\])(XN--CLCHC0EA0B2G2A9GCD|XN--HGBK6AJ7F53BBA|" \
          r"XN--HLCJ6AYA9ESC7A|XN--11B5BS3A9AJ6G|XN--MGBERP4A5D4AR|XN--XKC2DL3A5EE0H|XN--80AKHBYKNJ4F|" \
          r"XN--XKC2AL3HYE2A|XN--LGBBAT1AD8J|XN--MGBC0A9AZCG|XN--9T4B11YI5A|XN--MGBAAM7A8H|XN--MGBAYH7GPA|" \
          r"XN--MGBBH1A71E|XN--FPCRJ9C3D|XN--FZC2C9E2C|XN--YFRO4I67O|XN--YGBI2AMMX|XN--3E0B707E|XN--JXALPDLP|" \
          r"XN--KGBECHTV|XN--OGBPF8FL|XN--0ZWM56D|XN--45BRJ9C|XN--80AO21A|XN--DEBA0AD|XN--G6W251D|XN--GECRJ9C|" \
          r"XN--H2BRJ9C|XN--J6W193G|XN--KPRW13D|XN--KPRY57D|XN--PGBS0DH|XN--S9BRJ9C|XN--90A3AC|XN--FIQS8S|" \
          r"XN--FIQZ9S|XN--O3CW4H|XN--WGBH1C|XN--WGBL6A|XN--ZCKZAH|XN--P1AI|MUSEUM|TRAVEL|AERO|ARPA|ASIA|COOP|" \
          r"INFO|JOBS|MOBI|NAME|BIZ|CAT|COM|EDU|GOV|INT|MIL|NET|ORG|PRO|TEL|XXX|AC|AD|AE|AF|AG|AI|AL|AM|AN|AO|AQ|" \
          r"AR|AS|AT|AU|AW|AX|AZ|BA|BB|BD|BE|BF|BG|BH|BI|BJ|BM|BN|BO|BR|BS|BT|BV|BW|BY|BZ|CA|CC|CD|CF|CG|CH|CI|CK" \
          r"|CL|CM|CN|CO|CR|CU|CV|CW|CX|CY|CZ|DE|DJ|DK|DM|DO|DZ|EC|EE|EG|ER|ES|ET|EU|FI|FJ|FK|FM|FO|FR|GA|GB|GD|GE" \
          r"|GF|GG|GH|GI|GL|GM|GN|GP|GQ|GR|GS|GT|GU|GW|GY|HK|HM|HN|HR|HT|HU|ID|IE|IL|IM|IN|IO|IQ|IR|IS|IT|JE|JM|" \
          r"JO|JP|KE|KG|KH|KI|KM|KN|KP|KR|KW|KY|KZ|LA|LB|LC|LI|LK|LR|LS|LT|LU|LV|LY|MA|MC|MD|ME|MG|MH|MK|ML|MM|MN" \
          r"|MO|MP|MQ|MR|MS|MT|MU|MV|MW|MX|MY|MZ|NA|NC|NE|NF|NG|NI|NL|NO|NP|NR|NU|NZ|OM|PA|PE|PF|PG|PH|PK|PL|PM|" \
          r"PN|PR|PS|PT|PW|PY|QA|RE|RO|RS|RU|RW|SA|SB|SC|SD|SE|SG|SH|SI|SJ|SK|SL|SM|SN|SO|SR|ST|SU|SV|SX|SY|SZ|TC" \
          r"|TD|TF|TG|TH|TJ|TK|TL|TM|TN|TO|TP|TR|TT|TV|TW|TZ|UA|UG|UK|US|UY|UZ|VA|VC|VE|VG|VI|VN|VU|WF|WS|YE|YT|" \
          r"ZA|ZM|ZW)\b"
```

I am using a

```
with open(file, 'r') as f: 
    for m in re.finditer(key, text, re.IGNORECASE):
        try:
            m = str(m).split('match=')[-1].split("'")[1]
            new_file.write(m + '\n')
        except:
            pass
```

method to open, find and output to a new file.

Any assistance with speeding up this item and making it more efficient would be grateful.

Comment: That's horrifying.  Also, your email regex is wrong because it's not [two solid screenfuls of code](http://www.ex-parrot.com/pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html).

Comment: What exactly are you identifying? These regexes miss perfectly valid items. Is your data completely unstructured?

Comment: I need to see anything that matches valid IPv4 sha1 hashes urls domains and emails. I see that my regex is missing items and will update the regex to match but I am trying to get it to find matches to those item types faster. I currently output those item types to a text file for later parsing

Comment: Right but the code doesn't make sense. Urls can contain domain names so you're matching them twice. Where does `text` come from? Why are you turning the return of `finditer` into a string and then parsing that string? You want to match real TLDs but not specific protocols/schemes? And generally, I'm asking what you're trying to accomplish over what sort of data.

Comment: Overall concept is to parse indefinite amount and format of files containing random data. There's no specified format  of those item types. If it can be accomplished faster and more accurate is what I am looking for.

Comment: Running `str(m)` on a match object and parsing the result is wrong on so many levels. I suggest you look at the python `re` module documentation, specifically how to use match objects.

Comment: Again, are you looking for, http[s] urls? Any kind of url? gopher URL? what are you going to do with the resulting data? What happens if there is a false positive? Anything bad? Can you handle _some_ error rate? etc, etc.

Comment: @pvg my apologies I misunderstood, I am looking For any kind of URL. I am completely fine with false positives.

Comment: @interjay I appreciate the information and will dig into the documentation regarding re. Thank you for the guidance.

Comment: Then you should just loosen these regexes. You don't need to match tlds when matching urls, you should just match things that look url-like enough or email like enough. Basically, write a couple of naive, loose regexes and go to town.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want:

```
text = m.group(0)
print(text, file=new_file)
```